# I'm trying to create an onclicklistener that will call a function from another class

Tags: android, api, post, android-volley

The function will then send a json object onto a database using an API, but it seems that Volley.newRequestQueue(this); is a null value. it giving me this error:E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kevin.barcodescanner, PID: 11301
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.kevin.barcodescanner.AddToCart.jsonParse(AddToCart.java:59)
        at com.example.kevin.barcodescanner.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static TextView resultTextView;
Button scan_btn, add_btn;

AddToCart add = new AddToCart();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    scan_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
    add_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.add_btn);



    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanCodeActivity.class));
        }
    });

    add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            add.jsonParse();
        }
    });
}
```

}

public class AddToCart extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RequestQueue mQueue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
}

public void jsonParse() {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {

        json.put("id","11111111111");
        json.put("name","222222222222");
        json.put("price","1");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String url = "https://fg3qzgb2va.asdasdasdasdas-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sample";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.print("String Response : "+ response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag("VACTIVITY");
    mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is that since AddToCart is not really an activity the oncreate methode was never really called, since there is nothing to display. 
  A better solution would parse context from MainActivity to AddToCart via constructor and instantiate your queu in the constructor

```
public class AddToCart  {
private RequestQueue mQueue;
   public AddToCart(Context context) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    public void jsonParse() {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {

            json.put("id","11111111111");
            json.put("name","222222222222");
            json.put("price","1");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String url = "https://fg3qzgb2va.asdasdasdasdas-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sample";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.print("String Response : "+ response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setTag("VACTIVITY");
        mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: just a concern will "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" still work? because  savedInstanceState is not declared

Comment: savedInstanceState is a bundle of parameters you can use to resume an activity from a previous state. It have no relation with you current null pointer exception which is coming from the mQueu being null. The above posted code should handle it.

Comment: Lastly, how can I parse a context from the main activity to the AddToCart class were can I declare it? I'm honestly grateful to you for helping me out thanks.

Comment: You can instantiate the AddToCart in the onCreate method of your activity. It will be like  this.mAddToCart = new AddToCart(this);